# Reflection vs Coreflection

Tags: category-theory

Can someone intuitively explain the difference between a reflection and a coreflection? According to the definition, a reflection between categories A and B means that A is a sub-category of B where the inclusion functor from A to B has a left adjoint while in a coreflection the inclusion functor has a right adjoint.
Is there a standard method to check whether a functor B to A is the left or the right adjoint to the inclusion functor?

Comment: A necessary condition for an inclusion to be a reflection (resp. coreflection) is the preservation of limits (resp. colimits). For a sufficient condition you need to assume some properties of your categories and the functor (for more see the playlist on adjoint situations https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H8BknBKnJ8)